# Pre-Type in Powershell

Tags: powershell

I am doing some `kubernetes` hands-on and i am using `kubectl` in Powershell on a minikube cluster.

I found myself many times tired of having to type

```
kubectl do this
```

and then

```
kubectl do that
```

Is there any way to set **Powershell** to **pretype** `kubectl` after each press of Enter?

Comment: One suggestion is to use a function wrapper to only type part of it. `function c { kubectl $args }`. Now it would be `c do this`, and `c do that`.

Comment: @AbrahamZinala Actually my intention was to add a function Start-KubectlAutocomplete which would somehow modify the Input-Host in order to every time prepend kubectl,  so as i would have to write anything

Answer (score 3):

You can hijack the `CommandNotFoundAction` handler to "default" to `kubectl` commands when you enter a term that otherwise fails to resolve:

```
$ExecutionContext.InvokeCommand.CommandNotFoundAction = {
  param([string]$CommandName, [System.Management.Automation.CommandLookupEventArgs]$evtArgs)

  $kubectlCommands = -split 'annotate api-resources api-versions apply attach auth autoscale certificate cluster-info completion config cordon cp create debug delete describe diff drain edit exec explain expose get kustomize label logs patch plugin port-forward proxy replace rollout run scale set taint top uncordon version wait'

  if($CommandName -in $kubectlCommands){
    $evtArgs.CommandScriptBlock = {
      & kubectl $CommandName @args
    }.GetNewClosure()
    $evtArgs.StopSearch = $true
  }  
}
```

This will cause PowerShell to execute `kubectl` whenever the command name entered matches a kubectl command.

Beware this only works as a last resort - `cp something somewhere` will never execute `kubectl cp something somewhere` because `cp` can be resolved as a command name natively in PowerShell.

Comment: Thank you. It is a really nice way-around that solves my problem